# Limit of floor function and sine function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

for $$\lim_{x\to k}\lfloor x\rfloor \sin\frac{π x}2$$

find the limit for $k=0,1,2,3$

i started with

$$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$x\sin\frac{π x}2-\sin\frac{π x}2<\lfloor x\rfloor \sin\frac{π x}2\le x\sin\frac{π x}2$$

for $k= 0$ and for $k=2$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to k}x\sin\frac{π x}2-\sin\frac{π x}2=\lim\limits_{x\to k} x\sin\frac{π x}2= 0$$

and because of squeeze theorem $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\lfloor x\rfloor \sin\frac{π x}2=0$$

for $k=1$ and $k=3$ $$\lim\limits_{x\to k}x\sin\frac{π x}2-\sin\frac{π x}2=0$$ and

$$\lim\limits_{x\to k} x\sin\frac{π x}2= 1 , -1$$
so it means there is no limit at all? can i use sqeeze therom on the opposit and say that it represent the limit on the right and the limit on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sometimes use the Squeeze Theorem to show that a limit *does* exist, but never to show that a limit *does not* exist.  So your solutions are fine for $k=0$ and $k=2$ but you need to find an alternative for $k=1$ and $k=3$.

**Hint**.  Try taking the limit from the right and left separately.  If $3<x<4$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor=3$, so
$$\lfloor x\rfloor\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}=3\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}\ .$$
If $2<x<3$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor=2$ and so
$$\lfloor x\rfloor\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}=2\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}\ .$$
You can now find the limit for both of these as $x\to3$.  If the two limits have the same value then it is the value of
$$\lim_{x\to3}\lfloor x\rfloor\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}\ ,$$
if they are different (or if either does not exist) then this "two-sided" limit does not exist.